# Performance penalty using anonymous function in Julia

Tags: performance, anonymous-function, julia

I have noticed that there is a performance penalty associated with using anonymous functions in Julia. To illustrate I have two implementations of quicksort (taken from the micro performance benchmarks in the Julia distribution). The first sorts in ascending order

```
function qsort!(a,lo,hi)
    i, j = lo, hi
    while i < hi
        pivot = a[(lo+hi)>>>1]
        while i <= j
            while a[i] < pivot; i += 1; end
            while pivot < a[j]; j -= 1; end
            if i <= j
                a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
                i, j = i+1, j-1
            end
        end
        if lo < j; qsort!(a,lo,j); end
        lo, j = i, hi
    end
    return a
end
```

The second takes an additional parameter: an anonymous function that can be used to specify ascending or descending sort, or comparison for more exotic types

```
function qsort_generic!(a,lo,hi,op=(x,y)->x<y)
    i, j = lo, hi
    while i < hi
        pivot = a[(lo+hi)>>>1]
        while i <= j
            while op(a[i], pivot); i += 1; end
            while op(pivot, a[j]); j -= 1; end
            if i <= j
                a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
                i, j = i+1, j-1
            end
        end
        if lo < j; qsort_generic!(a,lo,j,op); end
        lo, j = i, hi
    end
    return a
end
```

There is a significant performance penalty when sorting Arrays of Int64, with the default version an order of magnitude faster. Here are times for sorting arrays of length N in seconds:

```
N       qsort_generic   qsort
2048    0.00125         0.00018
4096    0.00278         0.00029
8192    0.00615         0.00061
16384   0.01184         0.00119
32768   0.04482         0.00247
65536   0.07773         0.00490
```

**The question is**: Is this due to limitations in the compiler that will be ironed out in time, or is there an idiomatic way to pass functors/anonymous functions that should be used in cases like this?

**update** From the answers it looks like this is something that will be fixed up in the compiler.

In the mean time, there were two suggested work arounds. Both approaches are fairly straightforward, though they do start to feel like the sort of jiggery-pokery that you have to use in C++ (though not on the same scale of awkward).

The first is the FastAnon package suggested by @Toivo Henningsson. I didn't try this approach, but it looks good.

I tried out the second method suggested by @simonstar, which gave me equivalent performance to the non-generic qsort! implementation:

```
abstract OrderingOp
immutable AscendingOp<:OrderingOp end
immutable DescendingOp<:OrderingOp end
evaluate(::AscendingOp, x, y) = x<y
evaluate(::DescendingOp, x, y) = x>y

function qsort_generic!(a,lo,hi,op=AscendingOp())
    i, j = lo, hi
    while i < hi
        pivot = a[(lo+hi)>>>1]
        while i <= j
            while evaluate(op, a[i], pivot); i += 1; end
            while evaluate(op, pivot, a[j]); j -= 1; end
            if i <= j
                a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
                i, j = i+1, j-1
            end
        end
        if lo < j; qsort_generic!(a,lo,j,op); end
        lo, j = i, hi
    end
    return a
end
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have noted, the code you've written is idiomatic Julia and will someday be fast, but the compiler isn't quite there yet. Besides using FastAnonymous, another option is to pass types instead of anonymous functions. For this pattern, you define an immutable with no fields and a method (let's call it `evaluate`) that accepts an instance of the type and some arguments. Your sorting function would then accept an `op` object instead of a function and call `evaluate(op, x, y)` instead of `op(x, y)`. Because functions are specialized on their input types, there is no runtime overhead to the abstraction. This is the basis for [reductions](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/24d990ce3525fefd0318959500bced4ef611591c/base/reduce.jl#L11-L37) and [specification of sort order](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/24d990ce3525fefd0318959500bced4ef611591c/base/ordering.jl) in the standard library, as well as [NumericExtensions](https://github.com/lindahua/NumericExtensions.jl).

For example:

```
immutable AscendingSort; end
evaluate(::AscendingSort, x, y) = x < y

function qsort_generic!(a,lo,hi,op=AscendingSort())
    i, j = lo, hi
    while i < hi
        pivot = a[(lo+hi)>>>1]
        while i <= j
            while evaluate(op, a[i], pivot); i += 1; end
            while evaluate(op, pivot, a[j]); j -= 1; end
            if i <= j
                a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
                i, j = i+1, j-1
            end
        end
        if lo < j; qsort_generic!(a,lo,j,op); end
        lo, j = i, hi
    end
    return a
end
```

Answer (score 12):

It's a problem and will be fixed with an upcoming type system overhaul.

**Update:** This has now been fixed in the 0.5 version of Julia.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Good to know that there is no reason that anonymous functions like this can't be fast without resorting to "little tricks".

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's due to limitations in the compiler, and there are plans to fix it, see e.g. this [issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1864). In the meantime, the [FastAnonymous](https://github.com/timholy/FastAnonymous.jl) package might provide a workaround.

The way that you have done it looks pretty idiomatic, there's unfortunately no magic trick that you are missing (except for possibly the FastAnonymous package).

Comment: Thanks @Toivo, good to know that this is something that will be fixed. I had been wondering what sort of metaprogramming magic could be used to fix the problem, and it looks like FastAnonymous is the answer to that question.