# Pass a formula as a function parameter in Julia

Tags: julia, anonymous-function

I am trying to create a function that would allow for changing a formula and coefficients in Julia. I am 80% sure I should be using anonymous functions for this?

This SO post using python is a more discrete example of what I am trying to accomplish (in particular the base python example by chepner, rather than using a library). [Pass a formula as a function parameter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687219/pass-a-formula-as-a-function-parameter-in-python)

I also found this SO post using Julia that uses a type to store needed parameters and then pass them to a function. [How to pass parameter list to a function in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971681/how-to-pass-parameter-list-to-a-function-in-julia)

Using these as a base, this is what I have created so far:

```
   #Create composite type
   type Params
   formula
   b1::Float64
   b2::Float64
   end

   #create instance of type and load
    foo=Params((b1,b2,X)-> X^b1+X+b2,0.004,0.005)

   #create function
   function DoMath(X,p::Params)
   p.formula(X,varargs...) #??
   end
```

1. Am I on the right track as to how to structure this by using composite types and/or lambdas? I don't have any CS training and I am muddling my way through many concepts while trying to learn Julia.
2. What is the correct syntax for a function that can allow a user to change the formula and any coeffs. for a given X? Ultimately, I am imagining something with functionality like:

   ```
   DoMath(4) #some default formula with changing X
   DoMath(4, X*b1 +X*b2) #change X and change formula 
   DoMath(4, (X,b1,b2,b3)->X*b1+X*b2+x*b3) # change x, change formula to   a 3 parameter function
   ```

Thank you

**Update:** 
I got it working by following @Chris's syntax. One thing I had to tinker with is using

```
   (p::Params)(x) = p.formula(x,p.b) #p.b, not just b otherwise error
```

and I had to wrap the 2.0 and 3.0 in an array before calling

```
   p = Params((x,b)->x*b[1]+b[2],[2.0,3.0])
```

Comment: There is no performance penalty for Anon. Funcs in julia anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26175394/179081 So I've removed the link from your question. (Didn't seem critical part of it at all. Feel free to revert and enhance to make clearer if it was relievant)

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas's  https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/ParameterizedFunctions.jl may be of interest to you (It is probably only directly useful if you are doing Differential Equations; but I am not sure. It should still serve as an example of this kinda thing)

Comment: That looks interesting, isn't that the package from the modular algorithms article? I will try to tinker with that a bit and report back, the documentation explanation seems to be exactly what I was trying to articulate.

Comment: One can also implement a formula syntax which looks like R (eg. in [DataFrames.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/blob/master/src/statsmodels/formula.jl)), using macros, but that might be an overkill.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The idea is to build a callable type. A callable type is any type which has a "call". A function `f` is a callable type because you can call on it: `f(x)` for example. However, functions are not the only things that can act like functions. Indeed, in Julia, functions are basically callable types which `<: Function`.

So let's build one for your example. Make your type contain the data you want:

```
type Params
  b1::Float64
  b2::Float64
end
```

Now let's add a call to a `Params`. Let's say we want to do `x*b1 + b2`. We can make a call that does this by:

```
(p::Params)(x) = x*p.b1 + p.b2
```

Let's see how this works. Make a Params:

```
p = Params(2.0,3.0)
```

now we can calculate the formula by using its call:

```
p(4) # 4*2+3 = 11
```

Now see that `p` acts as a function which uses the internal data. This is it.

The rest is all building up from this same foundation. You need to respect the fact that Julia types are not dynamic. This is for good reasons. However, let's say you don't know how many b's you want. Then you can just have a field be an array of `b`'s:

```
type Params
  b::Vector{Float64}
end
(p::Params)(x) = x*b[1] + b[2]
```

Now let's say you wanted to be able to modify the formula. Then you can have a formula field:

```
type Params
  formula
  b::Vector{Float64}
end
```

and make the call throw the values into that:

```
(p::Params)(x) = p.formula(x,b)
```

Now if a user did:

```
p = Params((x,b)->x*b[1]+b[2],2.0,3.0)
```

then, as before:

```
p(4) # 4*2+3 = 11
```

Yay it acts the same, and still uses internal data.

But since `p` is just any ol' type, we can modify the fields. So here we can modify:

```
p.formula = (x,b)-> x*b[1]+x*b[2]+b[3]
push!(p.b,2.0) # p.b == [2.0,3.0,2.0]
```

and call again, now using the updated fields:

```
p(4) # 4*2 + 4*3 + 2 = 22
```

Indeed, as @LyndonWhite pointed out, ParameterizedFunctions.jl implements something like this. The strategy for doing so is callable types.

#### Extra little detail

Some libraries were built (incorrectly) requiring that the user pass in a function. So here we have a `p` that "acts like a function", but some libraries won't take it.

However, there is a quick fix. Just make it `<:Function`. Example:

```
type Params <: Function
  b1::Float64
  b2::Float64
end
```

Now things which require a function will take your `p` as it is a `<:Function`. This is just one way to point out that in Julia, `Function` is an abstract type, and each `function` is just a callable type which subtypes `Function`.

Comment: I am glad to see I was on the right track. So just to clarify for my own understanding, is (p::Params)(x) = x*p.b1 + p.b2 a constructor? 

I was reading about those last night, and was thinking that I was going to need to edit the params and formula in the type somehow and have the function just read from the type without modifying anything.

Comment: No, that is a call. If you treat the type you made like a function, that's the function it will call.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a similar pattern that I currently use for dealing with these "fixed parameters" vs "changing parameters" problems.
Fixed parameters are those do not often change when running a particular program(e.g. `b1`,`b2`,`b3`). Changing parameters are common variables(e.g. `x`) which almost keep changing between every function call. In many cases, using optional arguments or keyword arguments is enough to deal with the problem, but if we would like to change both function and its parameters simultaneously, this solution maybe not an ideal one. As the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971681/how-to-pass-parameter-list-to-a-function-in-julia) suggested, a better way would be to create a type and use multiple dispatch. However, we also need to manually `unpack` the type in the function body. In fact, we can write a more generic function wapper using `@generated` macro:

```
abstract FormulaModel

immutable Foo{F<:Function} <: FormulaModel
    formula2fixedparams::F
    fixedParam1::Float64
    fixedParam2::Float64
end
Foo(f, b1=5., b2=10.) = Foo(f, b1, b2)
Foo() = Foo((x,b1,b2)->x^b1+x+b2)  # default formula

immutable Bar{F<:Function} <: FormulaModel
    formula3fixedparams::F
    fixed1::Float64
    fixed2::Float64
    fixed3::Float64
end
Bar(b1,b2,b3) = Bar((x,b1,b2,b3)->b1*x+b2*x+b3*x, b1, b2, b3)
Bar() = Bar(1.,2.,3.)

@generated function DoMath(model::FormulaModel, changingParams...)
    fixedParams = [:(getfield(model, $i)) for i = 2:nfields(model)]
    func = :(getfield(model, 1))
    # prepare some stuff
    quote
        # do something
        $func(changingParams..., $(fixedParams...))
        # do something else
    end
end

julia> DoMath(Foo(), 4)
1038.0

julia> DoMath(Foo((x,y,b1,b2)->(b1*x+b2*y)), 4, 10)
120.0

julia> DoMath(Bar(), 4)
24.0
```